# Do you write helper methods when invoking production code in tests to hide some irrelevant details?

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, testing

Let's say that I have an example test case (written in Kotlin, but it doesn't matter here)

```
@Test
fun `should do something`() {
    // given
    val expected = "expected result"

    // when
    val result = productionClass.process("foo", null)

    //then
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expected)
}
```

As you can see I'm passing a `null` value as a second parameter to `process` method because it's not relevant in this case so I can ommit this.

But my concern is that every time I'm reading this test I'm wondering why this `null` value is passed and what does it mean in this context, so my solution to this problem is to create some helper method which hides this null for me. Then my test would looke like this

```
@Test
fun `should do something`() {
    // given
    val expected = "expected result"

    // when
    val result = process("foo")

    //then
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expected)
}

private fun process(foo: String): String {
    return productionClass.process(foo, null)
}
```

Then when I'm reading the test it's clear for me what is happening, but as always there are pros & cons of such solutions. These are the ones that I found:

**Pros**

- improved readability of the test
- small decoupling of production code from tests (change of the production API causes only this helper to break, not 100 other tests)
- hiding low level details from test, I'm only intrested in the result, it's not important here how it happens (maybe... or maybe I'm wrong here)

**Cons**

- I'm not really sure what the test does as it can do many weird things in this helper
- Creating one helper can lead to creation of many other helpers, and then I won't be able to find what is going on

I'm really curious about your opinion. How do you handle this problem? Or maybe it's not a problem at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give some arguments against the Pros listed...

The tests are (in my view) supposed to show exactly the method that is being exercised by the **when** condition for a test (in a Give-When-Then setup). So in terms of readability it means I have to read more code if another method is introduced (or several wrappers with various argument combinations) and does very little (if anything) to improve the situation, as now there's more lines of code rather than less and if there are several its going to get confusing real fast. Readability for me typically means more concise code/better named code, rather than an additional layer of redundancy that hides important details. **Unless** the argument list was particularly long. Then there are other well documented solutions for those situations like builders/factories/etc.

"Small decoupling" - Decoupling is to do with the dependence of one bit of code on another. Refactoring with most IDEs today is **very** easy with the right know-how... so its not necessary to have a method to make life easier - life already is relatively easy. Look at "select next instance of" functionality for when you've highlighted some bit of code, or "refactor method" which will typically allow the developer to reorder or change a method name/argument list to remove an argument from a method and cascade that change to all other call-sites. There's a measure known as fan-in/fan-out which can show how much one class depends on another when making or receiving method calls. This can highlight highly coupled code... delegating to another method does nothing to decouple code class-to-class.

Hiding low level details - unit testing is "white-box" testing. Testing source code where you do want to know the details. You don't really want to be hiding details at this level as the details matter. The more layers of indirection, the more places for bugs to hide. If the API is difficult or annoying to work with, the unit-testing should make this apparent and you can/should refactor, if you notice it, to make writing the tests clearer/easier.

Perhaps thinking there's a need for this sort of method is a clue that you need to break the method apart into multiple methods, so you can test functions more cleanly???

Comment: Thanks for your comment, based on that I also do believe that this API should be improved and then this problem won't appear at all. By a small decoupling I mean that I can avoid the situation when I'm changing the API and I need to fix many tests, so when it's hidden in this helper I need to change it in one place, but only if it's relatively small refactoring, but probably my IDE can handle this and I should not be worried about this situation

Comment: Hiding low level details - unit testing is "white-box" testing. Isn't this a problem when i'm testing what's happening under this API? Then any refactoring in this API causes my tests to break so probably I should avoid this kind of testing. But when we're talking only about the start of the call (executing the api) I should be explicit what I'm doing to clearly specify why "this" happens in my test

Comment: Does it changes anything when we are talking about the integration tests?

Comment: what IDE are you using?